# TypeError: 'module' object is not callable error in robot framework

Tags: testing, robotframework

I am not importing any classes. I am trying to initiate the test case for UI testing using Robot framework. Please find the below code.Can someone help me on this.

```
    *** Settings ***
Library    SeleniumLibrary
*** Test Cases ***
LoginTest
    create webdriver    chrome  executable_path="driver path"
    open browser    "https://innovate.dev-ais.corecompete.com/dashboard"    chrome
    click button    xpath=//span[text()='Sign In']//parent::button
```

I am receiving below error message.

```
    LoginTest                                                             | FAIL |
TypeError: 'module' object is not callable
------------------------------------------------------------------------------
TC001                                                                 | FAIL |
1 critical test, 0 passed, 1 failed
1 test total, 0 passed, 1 failed
```

Comment: I'm not sure about that problem, but you need to remove the quotes around `"https://..."` and `"driver path"`. I recommend running with `--loglevel DEBUG`, and then showing the stacktrace that appears in the log.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please do as it has been suggested in the comment section.

And I'd also say this could be caused by capitalization of `chrome`, because everywhere in the documentation the name of a browser is started with a capital letter (e.g. documentation of Selenium Library [here](https://robotframework.org/SeleniumLibrary/SeleniumLibrary.html#Open%20Browser)), so in your case, it would be `Chrome`. The same error message was described here: https://github.com/robotframework/SeleniumLibrary/issues/529#issuecomment-256335082 and the problem seemed to be with the capitalization.

Answer (score 1):

Remove the create webdriver line from above code

Put chromedriver.exe in python script folder (C:\Users\shankey\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\Scripts) and add this path in environment variable path (C:\Users...Python37\Scripts\chromedriver.exe).

Then, it should work fine.